# Need help storing data for different servers with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord.py

I want to ask how i would store variables for different servers since i have an "F" on message command that stores F's in json so that i can keep track of how many times it was called on different servers. I would also like to know how to dump this into json whenever the bot shuts down because right now the only way to dump is if i run the command aut.disconnect.

````
filename = "respectspaid.json"
respects = 0
with open(filename) as f_obj:
    respects = json.load(f_obj)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f"{message.channel}: {message.author}: {message.author.name}: {message.content}")
    cajo_guild = bot.get_guild(ID)

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.author.bot:
        return

    if "aut.membercount" == message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send(f"```py\n{cajo_guild.member_count}```")

    elif "F" == message.content:
        global respects
        respects += 1
        await message.channel.send(f"```Respects paid: {respects}```")

    elif "aut.disconnect" == message.content.lower():
        with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
            json.dump(respects, f_obj)
        print("Dumping and closing client...")
        await bot.close()
        sys.exit()

    await bot.process_commands(message)
````

I dump the updated F count when i disconnect the bot(when i turn off my PC) and load it when i run the program and update it every time "F" is sent but i don't know how to do this well on multiple servers. This bot will mainly be used for my friend's servers and i make the bot do some jokes that they want so i don't expect the bot to do some heavier stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a distinct count per server, you need to save the stats in a dict json file

So instead of having `respects += 1`, you'd do `respects[str(guild.id)] += 1`. This has the added bonus of not needing a global statement, as dicts are immutable. The reason for stringifying the guild ID is because while python dict keys can be ints, json object keys must be strings only.

To answer your other question, you have a couple options. The simplest is to save after each invocation:

```py
def save_respect():
    with open(fp, "w") as fh:
        json.dump(respects, fp, indent=4)
...
if message.content.lower() == "f":
    respects[str(message.guild.id)] += 1
    save_respects()
```

The alternate is to have a disconnect handler

```py
try:
    bot.run()
except BaseException:  # Catches keyboard interrupt
    pass
finally:
    save_respects()
```

though this will not handle cases where the code does not exit cleanly (such as system shutdown.)